# OpenCV error : Unsupported data type: INT32 in function 'getMatFromTensor'

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch

**I'm converting my MaskRCNN model to onnx with following codes below :**

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torchvision.models as models
import io
import torchvision
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor
from torchvision.models.detection.mask_rcnn import MaskRCNNPredictor

def create_model ():
  num_classes=2

  model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
  in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
  model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)
  #model.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=3, bias=True)
  in_features_mask = model.roi_heads.mask_predictor.conv5_mask.in_channels
  hidden_layer = 256
  model.roi_heads.mask_predictor = MaskRCNNPredictor(in_features_mask,
                                                        hidden_layer,
                                                        num_classes)
  return model

model=create_model()
weights = torch.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/model_best.pth",map_location='cpu')
model.load_state_dict(weights)
model.eval()

dummy_in = torch.randn(1, 3, 512, 512)
in_names = [ "actual_input_1" ] + [ "learned_%d" % i for i in range(2) ]
out_names = [ "output1" ]

import torch.onnx
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_in, "maskrcnn_yeni2.onnx", input_names=in_names, output_names=out_names, opset_version=11, verbose=True)
```

**after that, I'm getting a .onnx file and everything seems like okay**
**and I'm using OpenCV to read it**

```
import cv2
model_onnx=cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX("/content/maskrcnn_yeni2.onnx")
```

**I got this error**: I have searched and went through many similar errors but I couldn't find the solution

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp:155: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) 
Unsupported data type: INT32 in function 'getMatFromTensor'
```

**Also, when I'm trying with "onnx.load" method it works without problem:**

```
try:
    onnx.checker.check_model(model_onnx2)
except onnx.checker.ValidationError as e:
    print('The model is invalid: %s' % e)
else:
    print('The model is valid!')
```

output :

```
The model is valid!
```

Comment: "error: OpenCV(4.1.2)"  -- that's very old. first attempt to update that to current 4.5.5

Comment: @berak **OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/graph_simplifier.cpp:76: error: (-212:Parsing error) Input node with name onnx::Div_1614 not found in function 'getInputNodeId'**